# Creating an equinumerous disjoint set without axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Given a set $X$, can you always find a disjoint set $Y$ such that there is a bijection between them? This is easy with AC. you can well order X and replace each $x\in X$ with the least ordinal not already in $X$. I am unsure how to proceed without AC though.

Comment: What about $Y = X$?

Comment: If you want a disjoint set, just use $\{X\}\times X$.

Comment: @Brian: You still need to argue that $\{X\}\times X\cap X=\varnothing$.

Comment: @Asaf: Of course. And preferably not by claiming that $$\{X\}\times X\cap X=\{X\}\times(X\cap X)=\{X\}\times\varnothing=\varnothing\,.$$